Vuetify 3 How to prevent to close parent v-menu
enter image description here
Source Code Vuetify 3
<v-menu open-on-click :close-on-content-click="false">
      <template v-slot:activator="{props}" >
        <v-btn class="pa-2" v-bind="props">
          Ground Level
        </v-btn>
      </template>
      <v-card width="400" height="250" class="pa-2">
        <v-menu open-on-click :close-on-content-click="false">
          <template v-slot:activator="{ props }">
            <v-btn class="pa-2" v-bind="props">
              First Level
            </v-btn>
          </template>
          <v-card width="400" height="250" class="pa-2 ml-12">
            Second Level
          </v-card>
        </v-menu>
      </v-card>
    </v-menu>

After clicking outside, the first level pop up also closed.
How to click outside of Second Level and only close your text the Second Level pop up?
